# SQL Query for custom attribute

Tags: magento2, database, attributes, sql, query

I have create `custom attribute` in product `upc`

I want `custom query` (sql) to get `SKUs` and `UPCs`

Can anyone tell me the `related tables` from where I can get data, or if anyone can share query that would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Magento uses the Eav structure to save the product attribute value.

First, you have to find out your attribute type of `upc`.So, you have to open **eav_attribute** and run the below for getting `backend_type`]

> SELECT attribute_id,backend_type,attribute_code FROM `eav_attribute` where
> entity_type_id =4 and attribute_code ='upc'

Suppose, this attribute **backend_type** is  **varchar** then magento is save the value for products of this attribute at `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

Magento is saved product  lie entity wise like

```
Date time type attribute  to catalog_product_entity_datetime
Decimal/Price type attribute to catalog_product_entity_decimal
Image type attribute to  catalog_product_entity_gallery
Dropdown type attribute  to catalog_product_entity_int
Image type catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
Image type catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
Image type catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity
text type attribute  catalog_product_entity_text
tier price catalog_product_entity_tier_price
Varchar type attribute  to  catalog_product_entity_varchar
```

So, you have to find the appropriate table of this attribute then run below Query like:

> SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` where attribute_id
> =(SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` where entity_type_id =4 and attribute_code ='name')

Here I have done for the name attribute. For your case, you have to change `catalog_product_entity_varchar` with respect to your backend type of attribute.

If select specific attributes and their values below query helpful

```
select * from eav_attribute_option join eav_attribute_option_value on eav_attribute_option_value.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id where eav_attribute_option.attribute_id={attribute_id}
```